# Single quote(') and double quote (") strange behavior in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some questions regarding quotes usages.
For example, when i load a script or css in asp double quotes work fine, i use it like:

```
 <link href="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Styles/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But when i try to use the same same thing on a `background-image` it's not working as expected. Gives me an error:

> The funtion arguments are unclosed, ')' expected

```
  background-image: url("<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/image.jpg")%>");
```

Also, when i try to use the code specified above, visual studio highlights the `Page.ResolveClientUrl` correctly.

I fixed the above error by using single quotes (`), like:

```
 background-image: url('<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/image.jpg")%>')
```

It works fine, but visual studio doesn't highlight it as expected (I'm using the black background and the server tags `<% %>` are white on a yellow background and the text between the tags is white).

My questions are:

1. Why is it working with double quotes when loading scripts, but not when loading images within the `background-image` element.?
2. Why does visual studio highlight is as it's not server code?
3. What are other use cases where we should use single quotes instead of double quotes as in the above example?(except for string formatting as specified in the link below). One, two examples might be enough.

PS: I've read the difference between single and double quotes post (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433729/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-in-asp-net-4)) but this doesn't apply here.

Comment: Hope it will help you. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433729/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-in-asp-net-4?lq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433729/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-in-asp-net-4?lq=1)

Comment: @VinaySinha OP linked that question themselves.

Comment: Have you tried doubling up on the quotes to see if that changes anything?

Comment: @Takarii, if you mean like this: `background-image: url(""<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/image.jpg")%>"")` yes, but the same error appears

Comment: Could you fill in the full line for nav markup please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, but unrelated, the `nav` syntax is missing the `style` attribute.

Second, it really seems to be a problem with ASP.NET within style attributes. It works quite well as the full attribute value (as seen on the `link` tag). The `:` character may be the culprit.

What you can do:

First thing, there's no need to use `Page.ResolveClientUrl` with the `link` tag. You can use just the tilde path and ASP.NET will resolve the actual path.

From:

```
<link href="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Styles/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

To:

```
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

For the `nav` tag, try using a class and on the CSS side use a relative path:

HTML:

```
<nav class="nav-img" />
```

CSS:

```
.nav-img {
    background-image: url(../Content/image.jpg);
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET parses the path starting with tilde. It represents the application root, not website root. If you have a web application on your website like `www.mywebsite.com/myapp`, it points to `/myapp`.

Comment: Agreed with the comment, my bad there. The link tag was just an example of double quotes. Also edited question to remove the nav entirely (the html element is not relevant for the question.)

Comment: Also, i don't have a problem with my solution either, i was asking why the difference in usage /highlighting .

Comment: Honestly, don't know why it's getting lost. My bet is the `:` character, since it works when you use it as the full attribute's value, not just a part. I've tried on an MVC project and Razor shows the same behavior.